# Potential issues with working on the same document with Open Office and Word

Tags: microsoft-word, compatibility, openoffice, documents

I'm writing a report and plan to edit it using Open Office 3 and Word 2013. Open Office 3 can save in the .doc format but not .docx, which is the default of Word 2013. Will there be any compatibility issues or corruptions? For example is it possible for me to choose a format for tables in Word that Open Office doesn't support or vice-versa?

Answer (score 3):

Most of what Office can do with the .DOC Open Office, or LibreOffice are A-OK with. Corruptions are not really a concern. Formatting is the biggest problem I have. Items tend to shift around. Thats not a problem unless I move back and forth, I can do the creation and editing between multiple systems and then tweak it before I send the final copy. I then leave it it .doc or print to PDF for future use.

Another solution is Google Drive, you can import the document, and then edit it on Google from any machine without re-uploading / downloading. That also prevents the formatting errata.

Answer (score 2):

Microsoft provides a [very detailed list](http://office.microsoft.com/en-nz/word-help/differences-between-the-opendocument-text-odt-format-and-the-word-docx-format-HA010355788.aspx) of the features supported and unsupported when it comes to Word <-> Open Office interoperability. I often find myself refering to this list as well.